# IBM DB2 On Cloud - Exceeded maximum limit of 5 connections. Connection Refused

Tags: db2, node-red, dashdb

I have created a DB2 on the Cloud instance. I ran a few queries via Node-Red DB2 node before encountering the maximum connections exceeded error.

I have waited for more than 12 hours but none of the connection has been freed up. I can't view table within the DB2 service console.

Please advice what can I do to free up the connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Restart the app

Comment: Thanks. I have restarted the app but the connections are still not free up.